# How do I implement environment-specific configuration settings in AngularJS and Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017, angularjs-1.6, typescript2.4

I'm putting together a AngularJS+Typescript+VisualStudio project.  I want to have a configuration file with constants in it that control different settings (e.g., REST API URLs and environment names).  How is this typically done in this kind of project?

I might have a dev config file called `app.dev.config.ts` like this:

```
module app.config {
    export class ConfigSettings {
        static environment(): string { return "dev"; }
        static dataApiBaseUrl(): string { return "DevDataService"; }
    }
}
```

and an `app.prod.config.ts` like this:

```
module app.config {
    export class ConfigSettings {
        static environment(): string { return "prd"; }
        static dataApiBaseUrl(): string { return "PrdDataService"; }
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't actually work because these two classes have the same name.

I need to set this up in a way so that I build this only once in my build server, and then can deploy this to a fixed (3) number of environments.  Maybe this means that when I go to deploy this to some environment, I have an additional step where I rename a config file.  This is what I do for C# projects and their config files.

I've searched around online for this, but all I can find is references to `tsconfig.json` files.

Comment: Consider using a [constant provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this.

1) I put together separate config files like `env.dev.ts` and `env.prd.ts` in my project.  Their contents look like this:

```
angular.module('compdb') //module name matches my main module
    .constant('env', 'prd')
    .constant('key1', 'prd value 1')
    .constant('key2', 'prd value 2');
```

2) Visual Studio transpiles these to `env.dev.js`, etc.

3) In my gulp file, I copy the `env.*.js` files to my output directory.

4) In my `Index.cshtml` file, I include `env.js`.  I include this after my scripts that create the `compdb` angular module

5) When I deploy my code to any environment, I rename the appropriate config file (e.g., `env.prd.js`) to `env.js`